# List C++ Удаление конкретного элемента List

Tags: c++, stl

Нужно **удалить второй элемент** из  list. Все работает как надо. Но если я создаю 
функцию:
И вызываю её, то `ничего не происходит`. Почему это так, и как это исправить?

> ```
> auto delete_list_elem(list<int> list1, int k)
> {
>    int i=0;
>    list<int>::iterator it = list1.begin();
>    while(i<=k)
>    {
>      if(i==k)
>       {
>         cout << *it << " ";
>         return list1.remove(*it);
>
>         cout<<"\n deleted"<<endl;
>       }
>       it++;
>      i++;
>     }
> }
> ```

```
#include <iostream>
#include <list>     
#include <iterator> 
#include <ctime>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <algorithm>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
   list<int> myList; 
   for(int i = 0; i < 15; i++)
   {
       myList.push_back(rand()%20); 
   }

   cout << "Список: ";
   for ( list<int>::iterator it = myList.begin(); it != myList.end(); it++)
   {
    cout << *it << " ";
   }

   cout << "\n max: " << *max_element(myList.begin(),myList.end()) << endl;


   int i=0;
   int k=2; // удаление второго элемента
   list<int>::iterator it = myList.begin();
   while(i<=k)
   {
     if(i==k)
      {
        cout << *it << " ";    /// не работает при заносе в функцию
        myList.remove(*it);
        cout<<"\n deleted"<<endl;
      }
      it++;
     i++;
    }

   //delete_list_elem(myList,2);

  for ( list<int>::iterator it = myList.begin(); it != myList.end(); it++)
   {
    cout << *it << " ";
   } 


   return 0;
}
```

> **Update: ** Проблема решена, решение в моем ответе ниже.

Comment: Подозреваю, что дело в сигнатуре: `list<int> list1` передаёт в функцию *копию* списка, а не сам список.

Comment: @D-side, и что с етим делать?

Comment: Изучать С++ дальше, узнать про ссылки и обалдеть на пару минут.

Comment: Никода не пиши "using namespace std;" привыкнешь, потом проблем не оберешься. в std очень много всяких функций и классов и не всегда ты будешь котролировать какие заголовочные файлы подключатся вместе с твоим кодом, из-за это будут конфликты имен там где ты их не ожидаешь.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
auto delete_list_elem(list<int>& list1, int k) // <--- Тут & появился
{
   list<int>::iterator it = list1.begin();
   std::advance(it, k); // <-- advance итерирует переданный итератор на k позиций
   if (it != list1.end()) 
   {
       return list1.erase(it); // <--- Вернет итератор на k+1 элемент, перед it нет *
   }
   return it; // k больше размера списка, дефакто равет end()
}
```

Comment: Где вы комипилировали?

Comment: @AwesomeMan, Нигде не компилировал. Пардон, забыл синтаксит std::advance, сейчас поправил.

Answer (score 0):

**Update:**
Всем спасибо, спросил у преподавателя, он  внёс правки и все работает.
Код:

```
list<int> delete_list_elem(list<int> list1, int k)
{
   int i=0;
   list<int>::iterator it = list1.begin();
   while(i<=k)
   {
     if(i==k)
      {
        cout << *it << " ";
        list1.remove(*it);

        cout<<"\n deleted"<<endl;
      }
      it++;
     i++;
    }
    return list1;
}

**И данная строка была добавлена в код основной программы:**
```

> myList = delete_list_elem(myList,2);

Answer (score 0):

Всё верно. List - это не последовательный контейнер, как, например, vector. Поэтому к его итераторам нельзя использовать сложение/вычитание с натуральными числами. Нужно использовать специальные функции для перемещения итераторов типа prev(), next(), advance().